# How to show item from click without calling a method in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I want to click a job.id and then have it display list (name of job.names) below

Here is the example from a table

```
  <td>
    <ul>
      <template v-for='job in jobs'>
        <li @click="show list below job.id">{{ job.id }} </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </td>
```

How to I show name of job.names when i click on a job.id?

Comment: How does your list look like? Are you using a component to display the list?

Answer (score 0):

I not really konw what do you want to do. do you want to click job.id to toggle job detail just like this?

```
<ul>
  <template v-for='job in jobs'>
    <li>
      <span @click='showJob=job.id'>{{job.id}}</span>
      <ul :class="[showJob===job.id?'show':'hide']">
        <li v-for='name in job.names'>{{name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to click a job.id and then have it display list (name of job.names) below

Comment: So I've given the answer above.  you can display list by change class, or just use v-if

Answer (score 0):

you want to do it with a method? ok how about this

```js
data(){
 return {
  ...
  jobNames : []
 }
}
showList(i) {
 // if you wanna show them on console
 console.log(this.jobs[i].names)
 // if you wanna show them on the DOM
 this.jobNames = this.jobs[i].names;
}
```

```html
 <td>
    <ul>
      <template v-for='(job,i) in jobs'>
        <li @click="showList(i)">{{ job.id }} </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </td>
  
  <!-- you can place this anywhere you want inside your component template -->

  <ul>
   <li v-for='name in jobNames'>{{name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: As per title, OP wants it without calling a method.

Comment: as per comments , "How can I do this with a method? (without adding boolean to list) – david" @RuChernChong

Comment: He's contradicting with his title and comments.